# Get the query set for HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True)

Tags: python, django, templates, django-rest-framework, jinja2

How would I get the query set for a `HyperlinkedRelatedField` field within a template (or anywhere!).

I have tried with `many=False` and I am able to iterate over the instances with the code below, but not when `many=False`.

```
{% for atomic in serializer.atomic.queryset.all %}
    {{ atomic.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

On the flip side, I am able to get the field details by iterating over the field values, but this is not the same as the query set as it does not expose all the fields (please correct me if I'm wrong!!)

```
{% for atomic in serializer.atomic.iter_options %}
<option value="{{ atomic.value }}">{{ atomic.display_text }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging with `dir()` and `vars()` I eventually found one method to obtaining the queryset - it works for me, not sure if this is the correct way though!

```
{% for atomic in serializer.atomic.child_relation.queryset.all %}
    {{ atomic.name }}
{% endfor %}
```